# Problem fetching history of CPU with Zabbix API

Tags: asp.net, zabbix

I'm newbie with Zabbix.

Firstly, i'm getting the itemIDs of key"system.cpu.[,user]" and ""system.cpu.load[percpu,avg1]". Now, i'm interessed to fetch history data of these itemIDs (key"system.cpu.[,user]","system.cpu.load[percpu,avg1]") to fetch previous CPU utilization of VM's. However, when make http.get(history.get) with the next parameters:

```
"method": "history.get",
"params": {
    "output": "extend",
    "history": 0,
    "itemids": "28887", --> itemID of system.cpu.[,user]
    "sortfield": "clock",
    "sortorder": "DESC",
    "limit": 10
}
```

The response is always 0 results. But with anothers itemsIds, the response fetch many results.

Someone can help me what is going wrong please?
PS: I'm using zabbix .NET SDK API, but i tryed with other packages the response was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay particular attention to the type of data you request: the `history` parameter possible values are:

- 0 = numeric float;
- 1 = character;
- 2 = log;
- 3 = numeric unsigned;
- 4 = text.

See: [history/get](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/history/get)

Comment: Wow...history = 0 solve my problem.  Guy, you saved my day! Thank you so much!